# One-hot encoder for SQL-like row data in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, one-hot-encoding

I have data that follows the below format. The first column is of little interest to me; columns two and three, however, are a job title and an example skill that this title likely has (economists at Bureau of Labor Statistics produced this data.)

```
O*NET-SOC Code  Title               Example 
11-1011.00      Chief Executives    Adobe Systems Adobe Acrobat 
11-1011.00      Chief Executives    AdSense Tracker 43232306    
11-1011.00      Chief Executives    Atlassian JIRA
```

I want to find a one-hot vectorization where jobs are rows and skills are columns; a cell (j,s) receives the value 1 if the corresponding job requires the corresponding skill (else 0).

Below is my "hard way" approach to achieving this affect. Is there, however, an easier pandas approach to produce the same result?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

skill_data = pd.read_csv('Technology Skills.csv')
jobs = [job for job in skill_data['Title'].unique()]
skills = [skill for skill in skill_data['Example'].unique()]
job_skill_dict = {name:[] for name in jobs}

for idx,row in skill_data.iterrows():
  job_skill_dict[row[1]].append(row[2])

job_skill_vectors = {name:[] for name in jobs}
for job, skill_list in job_skill_dict.items():
  job_skill_vectors[job] = [1 if skill in skill_list else 0 for skill in skills]

vectors = [job_skill_vectors[job] for job in jobs]
job_skill_matrix = np.array(vectors)
```

What I'm doing essentially is creating a list of unique job titles, then a list of unique skills, then creating a dictionary with job titles as keys and empty lists as values. Then I iterate through the dataframe rows, appending skills to the lists (values) of the dictionary just mentioned. Next, I make another dictionary with job titles as keys and empty lists as values; This time, I apply a one hot encoding, which where 1 or 0 is present for each skill in the order of the skills list. Lastly, I dump all of these dictionary values (lists of one hot vectors) into a giant list in order of the jobs list. Lastly, I create a numpy array from this list of lists...

The final result looks like this (which is desired!)

```py
job_skill_matrix
>>>
array([[1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 1]])
```

As I'm sure you can tell, this is not optimal, for both computational reasons as well as the room for user error (many variables would need to be renamed to repeat this process on new data.)

If there's a simple way to accomplish this effect, I'm really interested!

Comment: try using sqlalchemy library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Title')['Example'])
```

if you want a `numpy`:

```
df_dummies.to_numpy()
#df_dummies.values
```

Also we can use something like:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Title', columns='Example', aggfunc='any').astype(int)
```

but this would return a somewhat different array